# Group more than one columns in rdlc report with multilevel grouping

Tags: report, rdlc

I have a report where I want to display data obtained by a stored procedure which returns single table.

## Columns returned from stored procedure

Client #, Client Name, Client Phone #

Project #, Project Description

Test #, Test Name, Test Description

Container #, Container Description, Container Parameter

## Relationship between tables

Client  - Project   1-N(one to many)

Project - Test 1-N(one to many)

Test - Container 1-N(one to many)

## Desired format to be displayed

```
Client #  :  XYZ               Client Name : Patterson, Celeste              Phone # (XXX) XXX-XXXX

          Project #: P1                    Project Description: Project 1 Data

                       Test #      Test Name     Test Description   Container #     Container Description  Container Parameter

                          T1            Test 1             Test Data             C1                      Container Data           C1 Parameter

                          T1            Test 1             Test Data             C2                      Container 2 Data        C2 Parameter

                          T2            Test 2             Test 2 Data          C1                      Container 1 Data        C1 Parameter

                          T2            Test 2             Test 2 Data          C3                      Container 3 Data        C3 Parameter

          Project #: P2                    Project Description: Project 2 Data

                       Test #      Test Name     Test Description   Container #     Container Description  Container Parameter

                          T1            Test 1             Test Data             C1                      Container Data           C1 Parameter

                          T1            Test 1             Test Data             C2                      Container 2 Data        C2 Parameter

                          T2            Test 2             Test 2 Data          C1                      Container 1 Data        C1 Parameter

                          T2            Test 2             Test 2 Data          C3                      Container 3 Data        C3 Parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can Add 3 groups.

```
1 Group:Client
```

In this group u can add client description etc.

In the Same way other 2 groups

```
2 Group:Project 

3 Group:Test
```

This Will Display the Data the format you Needed.