# RDLC report with multiple column data display

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have a report whose dataset is as below:

```
ID SeqID Text DisplayName DisplayValue 

1   x    xyz   xyz1           []

1   x    xyz   xyz2           [x]

1   x    xyz   xyz3           []

1   x    xyz   xyz4           [X]

1   x    xyz   Other           

2   y    abc   abc1           []

2   y    abc   abc2           [X]

2   y    abc   abc3           []

2   y    abc   abc4           [X]

2   y    abc   Other
```

The above dataset has to below displayed in the below format in my report:

```
1 xyz

xyz1 [] xyz2 [x] 

xyz3 [] xyz4 [x]

Other: 

2 abc

abc1 [] abc2 [x]

abc3 [] abc4 [x]

Other:
```

I'm trying to convert a crystal report that is in the above format to an RDLC report in VS2008 Basically I need a dynamic column display for each of the unique text column values.
Any suggestions would be greatly helpful

Comment: Will there only ever be those 5 rows for each `ID` value?

Comment: No, there could be more/less rows for each ID value

Comment: Could be helpful... http://stackoverflow.com/q/8297333/945456